# Edit (adjacent) cells with Find()

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a small macro for searching and sorting barcodes.

The idea is that barcodes are scanned into cell C1, then the macro is suppose to count the amount of times the same code is scanned. If the barcode is not already in the list (column B:B) it should add the new barcode in the list (column B:B).

I've managed utilised the Find() syntax, however I can't manage to edit any cells with it. Only thing I am able to do is MsgBox " "  Ive tried:

```
Range("a5").Value = 5
```

It doesn't work

This is the code I currently have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
    If Range("C1") = "" Then MsgBox "No input"

    Dim barcodes As Range        
    Set barcodes = Range("B:B").Find(What:=Range("C1").Value, After:=Range("B2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, MatchByte:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not barcodes Is Nothing And Not Range("C1") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Found"
    End If

    If barcodes Is Nothing And Not Range("C1") = "" Then
        MsgBox "New product"
    End If
End Sub
```

For `MsgBox "Found"` I want instead a code that counts the amount of times the same barcode has been scanned in the adjacent cell to the right.

And for `Msgbox "New product"` I want to write a part that adds the new code to the list in this case Column B:B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the below will **A)** verify that you don't have a match (using `IsError`, which returns boolean) to determine if you need to add a value and start the scan count at 1, or **B)** if you need to find the previous entry (using `Match()`) and add to the counter:

```
If IsError(Application.Match(Cells(1,3).Value,Columns(2),0)) Then 
    lr = cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).row
    Cells(lr+1,2).Value = Cells(1,3).Value
    Cells(lr+1,1).Value = 1
Else 
    r = Application.match(Cells(1,3).Value,Columns(2),0)
    cells(r,1).value = cells(r,1).value + 1
End If
```

---

**Edit1:**

Updated column #s for second subroutine per comment from OP, while stripping out the first subroutine and rewording.

Comment: Thank you, Currently Column A:A is called Units so the amount of time a code has been scanned. Column B:B is a list with barcodes ,currently empty. When I scan a new barcode the macro should add the barcode to column B:B and a +1 in column A:A next to its corresponding barcode.

Comment: @M.W. then you just need to update the column references in the `Else` section from 3 to 1 (column A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, etc.).  This would fulfill the needs, where if it's not matched in column 2 (B) it is added to the last row + 1, assuming there is a header , the first row to have data is 2.

Comment: Big thanks to you, however there is one problem it keeps adding 93 so, +93 instead of +1

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Hi do you also know how I  can move the edited row to the top off my list? So basically a barcode is scanned and is placed in row 100 "or whatever"  but I want it to appear in row 4

Answer (score 0):

With this code you will need a sheet called "DataBase" where you will store each scan and later will be the source for example for a pivot table:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Barcode As String, i As Long, wsDB As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Dim DictBarcodes As New Scripting.Dictionary 'You need to check the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference for this to work

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set wsDB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataBase")

    With Target
        If .Range("C1") = vbNullString Then MsgBox "No input"
        On Error Resume Next

        'loop through all the barcodes and store them into a dictionary
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If .Cells(i, 2) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'skip the loop once a blank cell is found
            DictBarcodes.Add .Cells(i, 1), i 'this will raise an error if there are duplicates
        Next i

        'If the value doesn't exist we add it to the list
        If Not DictBarcodes.Exists(.Cells(1, 3)) Then
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(LastRow, 2) = .Cells(1, 3)
        End If
    End With

    'Either it exists or not, store it to the data base to keep tracking
    With wsDB
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Barcode"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Date Scan"
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(LastRow, 1) = .Cells(1, 3)
        .Cells(LastRow, 2) = Now
    End With

    'Finally the output on the adjacent cell
    Target.Cells(1, 4) = Application.CountIf(wsDB.Range("A:A"), Target.Cells(1, 3))

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you , but what I want is that the list should be created while the barcodes get scanned, because the excel sheet needs to be empty every time it is going to be used. The files are going to be saved by date and every day a new shipments of goods come in they al have new barcodes and need to be added to the list and counted.

Comment: My code adds new barcodes to the list and count them... check it out. thought you need to create a tab called "DataBase" to keep track of everything